# How to create another table in database with SugarORM

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sugarorm

I have an application and I'm using [Sugar ORM library v1.5](https://github.com/chennaione/sugar) to create database. I released first version of app and now I want to add another table to database, I installed new version on previous version but it crashes. This is the error I've got. How can I solve it? Should I increase the version of database?

Thanks in advance

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: CUSTOMER_SERVICE_REPORT (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO CUSTOMER_SERVICE_REPORT(SERIAL_NUMBER,COSTUMER_NAME,DATE,DESCRIPTION,FACTOR,SERVICE_ID,ID,CHECK_LIST_NUMBER,REMINDER) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:501)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1546)
    at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:280)
    at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:416)
```

Comment: increase the VERSION metadata field in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @Prasanth S's comment, just adding new tables only requires incrementing the `VERSION`, so Sugar ORM knows to look for new tables.

However, if you wish to make other data changes, you'll need to set up a migration script. This can be done by adding `<version>.sql` in `/assets/sugar_upgrades/`. For example, adding `3.sql` will cause this file to be run when migrating to version 3.

The SQL file just contains a list of SQL commands to run on your local SQLite database.

More info is in [the official documentation](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/migration.html).